# Selenium python : element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from this website [example website](https://noc.esdc.gc.ca/)

I need to get the version 2021 and search by code.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9515')
options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver"), options=options)
url = "https://noc.esdc.gc.ca/"
driver.get(url)

search_by_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)\
                        .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")))
# click to activate this option
search_by_code.click()

text_area = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)\
                        .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/details[2]/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/input")))

version = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)\
                        .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/details[2]/div/div/form/div/div[1]/select"))))

search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/details[2]/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div/button')

# select version 2021
version.select_by_value('2021.0')

# click on text area
text_area.click()

# type the text 
text_area.send_keys("10010  –  Financial managers")

# click the button
search_button.click()

print(source = driver.current_url)
```

I am not sure what I have missed? I added some comments to describe the logic.

Comment: Have you tried just sending `Financial managers` without the prefix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `python-requests` library for this website. I have done a little script below to send requests and get the data. You can send your query to `SearchCriteria.CodeSearch` value. You can use `BS4`, `LXML`, or `Scrapy Selector class` and target the values by `XPATH` or a `CSS selector`.

```
import re
import requests

cookies = {
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'u4qffsgfreddkgvdphaxo3pc',
    'BIGipServernoc_esdc_gc_ca_http_443.app~noc_esdc_gc_ca_http_443_pool': '639114412.20480.0000',
    'gpv_pthl': 'blank%20theme',
    'gpv_pc': 'Employment%20and%20Social%20Development%20Canada',
    'gpv_pqs': 'blank%20query%20string',
    'gpv_pu': 'noc.esdc.gc.ca%2FSearch%2FQuickSearchJobTitleResults',
    'gpv_pt': 'Search%20by%20job%20title%20-%20Results%20-%20Canada.ca',
    's_plt': '9.44',
    's_tp': '1206',
    'gpv_url': 'noc.esdc.gc.ca%2FSearch%2FQuickSearchJobTitleResults',
    's_ips': '741',
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-PK,en;q=0.9,ur-PK;q=0.8,ur;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5,sv;q=0.4,it;q=0.3',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=u4qffsgfreddkgvdphaxo3pc; BIGipServernoc_esdc_gc_ca_http_443.app~noc_esdc_gc_ca_http_443_pool=639114412.20480.0000; gpv_pthl=blank%20theme; gpv_pc=Employment%20and%20Social%20Development%20Canada; gpv_pqs=blank%20query%20string; gpv_pu=noc.esdc.gc.ca%2FSearch%2FQuickSearchJobTitleResults; gpv_pt=Search%20by%20job%20title%20-%20Results%20-%20Canada.ca; s_plt=9.44; s_tp=1206; gpv_url=noc.esdc.gc.ca%2FSearch%2FQuickSearchJobTitleResults; s_ips=741',
    'Origin': 'https://noc.esdc.gc.ca',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Referer': 'https://noc.esdc.gc.ca/Search/QuickSearchJobTitleResults',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}

data = {
    'SearchCriteria.CodeVersion': '2021.0',
    'SearchCriteria.CodeSearch': '10010  –  Financial managers',
    'btn-submitSearchNOC': 'Search',
}

r = requests.post('https://noc.esdc.gc.ca/Search/QuickSearchJobTitleResults', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
id_ = re.findall(r'objectid=(.*?)&', r.text)[0]

url = f'https://noc.esdc.gc.ca/Structure/NocProfile?objectid={id_}'
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate how to get the cookies and headers ? Did you copy-paste them  using inspect tools on chrome ?

Comment: Yes, you can copy cookies and headers from the chrome network tab. Just open the network tab and send a request to the website. The easiest way is to coy the cURL command of the request and paste to this website: https://curlconverter.com/ this will convert the cURL command to a python requests code.

Comment: if the cookies and the headers are not general for all codes, it is complicated because each time I have to copy-paste them manually.

Comment: No, you don't have to copy-paste headers or cookies. They will work with all the requests. Could you share the code which gave you the error so I can look into this?

Comment: The code you are searching for doesn't return any data but an error on the website. You can put it in a try-except block like this.

`try:
    id_ = re.findall(r'objectid=(.*?)&', r.text)[0]
except Exception:
    print("ID not found")
    exit()` 

If you are using a loop then put `continue` instead of `exit()`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think so. If you enter this code in the website , you will get data. In fact, there are more than 500 code, if you try anyone of them, you will get this error. I am not a web dev expert but I think the header and cookies are really related to that first code.

Comment: I tried earlier with this string `10010  –  Financial managers` on the website and I got an error. Now it's running displaying the data fine and the script is alow running fine. You can run the same script again and see if you still get an error. I think it was a website issue, not the script.

Comment: Where did you get `SearchCriteria.CodeVersion` ?In the code source it is called `QuickSearchModel.CodeVersion`. However, when I change the code by the `QuickSearchModel.CodeVersion`, it does not work! It is really weird. Same thing for `SearchCriteria.CodeSearch`

Comment: If you use the `Network` tab and make the request, you will see all of these values there. You should not change it otherwise it won't work.